# Error Message in woocommerce login form

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I could not find default error where to change.
There is the error message screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `woocommerce/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php` On the line 779

```
if ( empty( $username ) ) {
                throw new Exception( '<strong>' . __( 'Error', 'woocommerce' ) . ':</strong> ' . __( 'Username is required.', 'woocommerce' ) );
            }
```

Comment: there is another error message ... where is come form ?
http://postimg.org/image/uliuo4zep/
please help.

Comment: same file, line 198, can you try?

Comment: have a look into the options on woocommerce inside the admin, I'm not able to find this on the code. What's the version of woocommerce are you using?

Comment: Woocommerce vesion : 2.5.5

Comment: Could you try this in the functions.php on your theme?

 `//Change login errors
add_filter('login_errors', create_function('$a', "return '<b>Error:</b> Invalid Username or Password';"));`

Comment: I do that but still showing the msg like ... "ERROR: INVALID USERNAME. LOST YOUR PASSWORD?"

Comment: replace that line for `add_filter('login_errors', create_function('$a', "return '<b>Error:</b> Usuario o contraseña invalido';"));` and let me know if changed,should be change.

Comment: it still showing this msg : ERROR: INVALID USERNAME. LOST YOUR PASSWORD?

Comment: can u provide the link?